# replaceWith() P by Span keeping the actual content

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I can't seem to replace p tag with span keeping the actual content.
If you can help me thanks.

```
$('.anim-letters p').replaceWith( "<span class='letters'>" + $('this').text() + "</span>" );
```

With code above the content is duplicated.
With the code bellow the content disappear :

```
$('.anim-letters p').replaceWith( "<span class='letters'>" + $('.anim-letters p').text() + "</span>" );
```

Comment: Do you have more that one `p` element? Can you paste the HTML code as well?

Comment: first the html code is generated by the plugin Visual composer (wordpress). the html code is : <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  fweight700 fsizeslogan itic colorw txtshdow anim-letters" style="opacity: 1;">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper text-wrapper"><div class="line line1"></div>
   <p class="letters">JUST AT THE RIGHT TIME <br/>IN THE RIGHT PLACE</p
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: the code after jquery is applied :<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  fweight700 fsizeslogan itic colorw txtshdow anim-letters" style="opacity: 1;">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper text-wrapper"><div class="line line1"></div>
   <span class="letters">JUST AT THE RIGHT TIMEIN THE RIGHT PLACE</span>
<span class="letters">JUST AT THE RIGHT TIMEIN THE RIGHT PLACE</span>

  </div>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var text = $('.anim-letters p').text();
```

or

```
var text = $('.anim-letters p').html();

$('.anim-letters').append( "<span class='letters'>" + text + "</span>" );
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the first solution duplicate the text and the second i can't use them because the "p" tag is generated by tinyMCE and i would change the text at any time. Too, I noticed that "Anime letters" code work only with one line and I have two.

Comment: the second solution work with "replaceWith()" instead of "append()", but only the first paragraph is taken into account. I have two line/paragraph